Hyperledger Fabric - Prometheus's index ledger_transaction_count is different as the transaction on chain
Hyperledger Fabric: v2.5.2
I have a Grafana and Prometheus, one of the index 'Ledger Transaction Count' or ledger_transaction_count is showing different transaction numbers on-chain of the sum of my multiple chaincodes, which the Grafana's number is less than the transaction count on-chain.
For example:
Grafana: 30,000
Transaction on-chain: 50,000
Here is the information I copied from the Grafana about this index
{
  "datasource": {
    "type": "prometheus",
    "uid": "P1809F7CD0C75ACF3"
  },
  "description": "Number of transactions processed.",
  "fieldConfig": {
    "defaults": {
      "unitScale": true,
      "mappings": [
        {
          "options": {
            "match": "null",
            "result": {
              "text": "N/A"
            }
          },
          "type": "special"
        }
      ],
      "thresholds": {
        "mode": "absolute",
        "steps": [
          {
            "color": "#73BF69",
            "value": null
          },
          {
            "color": "#FADE2A",
            "value": 500
          },
          {
            "color": "#d44a3a",
            "value": 800
          }
        ]
      },
      "color": {
        "mode": "thresholds"
      },
      "unit": "none"
    },
    "overrides": []
  },
  "gridPos": {
    "h": 4,
    "w": 4,
    "x": 12,
    "y": 1
  },
  "id": 37,
  "links": [],
  "maxDataPoints": 100,
  "options": {
    "reduceOptions": {
      "values": false,
      "calcs": [
        "sum"
      ],
      "fields": "/^Value$/"
    },
    "orientation": "auto",
    "textMode": "auto",
    "wideLayout": true,
    "colorMode": "value",
    "graphMode": "none",
    "justifyMode": "auto",
    "showPercentChange": false
  },
  "pluginVersion": "10.3.3",
  "targets": [
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "P1809F7CD0C75ACF3"
      },
      "editorMode": "code",
      "exemplar": false,
      "expr": "sum(ledger_transaction_count{chaincode!=\"unknown\"})",
      "format": "table",
      "hide": false,
      "instant": true,
      "interval": "",
      "legendFormat": "__auto",
      "range": false,
      "refId": "A"
    }
  ],
  "title": "Ledger Transaction Count",
  "type": "stat"
}

Does anyone know how this metric is represented?
Thank you.
It's expecting Grafana to show the correct total transaction count from my multiple chaincodes
